# Seek Pagination with Knex library for Postgress

Tags: javascript, postgresql, pagination, knex.js

Attempting to implement cursor based pagination - and I would like to know the proper way to call it with `Knex` for `Postgres`.

Here is the standard statement:

```
SELECT 
FROM 
WHERE (timestamp, id) > (cursor.age, cursor.id)
ORDER BY timestamp ASC, id ASC
LIMIT
```

And my attempt with `Knex`:

```
const knexResult = await knex({ 'table_name' })
    .select(columns)
    .where('created_at', '>', cursor.timestamp)
    .andWhere('id', '>', cursor.id)
    .orderBy(['timestamp', 'id'])
    .limit(first)
  return knexResult;
```

Is this the proper way to call it - it seems not correct... I am trying to avoid `knex.raw`

**Edit**

The SQL standard for the statement `(x,y) > (a,b)` is true if:

```
                          (x > a or (x = a and y > b))
```

The code above gives no-results because I believe its trying to match both `where` clauses.

Comment: Are you getting a bug/error, or are you asking about best practice? If seeking best practice, I would recommend https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Allxie, questions seeking generic best-practice guidance are out of scope for Code Review, where _specific concrete code_ is reviewed.  The code must be _working_, too, and that doesn't seem to be the case here ("_it seems not correct..._").  Code for review generally needs more context than has been provided here.

Comment: does this link (https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/219782/efficient-pagination-for-big-tables) help you?

Comment: @Mark Thank you for the link - however, I am looking for the Knex implementation

Comment: @TobySpeight-- Agreed. The original edit of the question looked like a "I have this code but I think it might not be the best practice".

Answer (score 1):

You can implement this boolean condition `(x > a or (x = a and y > b))`  with knex.

```js
const knexResult = await knex({ 'table_name' })
    .select(columns)
    .where('created_at', '>', cursor.timestamp)
    .orWhere((inner) => 
       inner.where('created_at', '=', cursor.timestamp)
            .andWhere('id', '>', cursor.id)
    )
    .orderBy(['timestamp', 'id'])
    .limit(first);

  return knexResult;
```

It will produce:

```sql
Select `col1`, `col2` from `table_name` where `created_at` > '12323112' or (`created_at` = '12323112' and id > '23')
Order by `timestamp`, `id`
Limit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done easily with [knex-relay-cursor-pagination](https://github.com/brietsparks/knex-relay-cursor-pagination), if relay-style pagination is an acceptable solution

```
  const pagination = createPagination({
    from: 'table_name',
    sortColumn: 'created_at',
    sortDirection: 'desc',
    cursorColumn: 'id',
    first,
    after,
    last,
    before,
  });

  const rows = await this.db.from('table_name')
    .where(pagination.where.column, pagination.where.comparator, pagination.where.value)
    .orderBy(pagination.orderBy.column, pagination.orderBy.direction)
    .limit(pagination.limit)
    .select('*');

  return pagination.getPage(rows);
```